# What's the minimal $k$ satisfying these conditions? Graph theory problem.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, contest-math, extremal-combinatorics

I'm thinking following problem.

> There are five pairs of couples (So, ten people total) and $k$ clubs satisfying following three conditions. Let $A,B$ are arbitrary people among those 10,
>
> 1. If $A$ and $B$ are a couple, they never belong to same club.
> 2. If $A$ and $B$ are two people and not a couple, *exactly one* club contains both of them.
> 3. There exists at least one person that belongs to exactly two clubs.
>
> What is the minimum number $k$ satisfying above conditions?

I believe the graph theoretic interpretation is useful to solve this problem. To get some intuition, I tried three couples case. and it seems minimal $k$ is $4$, I think. but for the case of five couples, I still don't know. Is there any systematic way to approach these kinds of problems? Also, can we solve above problem for arbitrary $n$ couples case?

Comment: Would the minimal value of k be 4 in the case where there are only 2 couples?

Comment: @user84413 Yes, minimal value becomes 4 if there are two couples.

Comment: Consider the primal graph $G$ of the hypergraph $H$ that has people as vertices and clubs as edges. $G$ has people as vertices; two people are adjacent in $G$ when they both belong to the same club. By condition 1, $G$ is the complement of a perfect matching with $2n$ vertices. The question asks for a kind of "special" edge clique cover number of $G$; condition 2 restricts attention to edge clique covers in which any pairwise intersection is a singleton, and condition 3 requires some vertex in every such special edge clique cover to appear in precisely two cliques.

Comment: The third condition tells you that there are two clubs containing five people. The remaining clubs can have sizes either two or three. It is not hard to see that the optimal solution has the maximal number of clubs of size 3: you are trying to place each pair of non-couple elements in a club together, and a club of size 3 takes care of 3 of the remaining pairs, whereas a club of size two just accounts for 1. In the case where number of couples is a parameter k, third condition tells you there are two clubs of size k. Once again remaining clubs have size 2 or 3 and solution is the same.

Comment: Note that this is also the minimal solution even when the third condition is removed.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is $\mathbf{k = 14}$.

Consider the more general question where the number of couples is a parameter.
In the case of just one couple the minimal system has $k=3$, with one person belonging to two clubs, and the other person belonging to a different club.
Therefore suppose there are $n\ge 2$ couples.

Condition 3 implies that there is some person $u$ in precisely two clubs $C$ and $D$.
Suppose $v$ is some person not in $C$ or $D$; in particular, $v\ne u$.
By condition $2$, if $v$ and $u$ are not a couple, then they must be in some club in common, so $v\in C$ or $v\in D$, a contradiction.
Hence $v$ is the unique partner of $u$.
It follows that $C$ and $D$ have $2n-1$ members between them.
By condition 2 the unique member common to both $C$ and $D$ is $u$.
Moreover, no club can have more than $n$ members by condition 1 and the pigeonhole principle.
Hence both $C$ and $D$ have exactly $n$ members.

Now consider two people $x\in C\setminus \{u\}$, $y\in D\setminus \{u\}$.
If $x$ and $y$ are a couple then there must be some clubs $E_{xv|y}$ and $E_{yv|x}$ such that $x\in E_{xv|y}$ and $y\in E_{yv|x}$, and (by condition 2) clubs $E_{xv|y}$, $E_{yv|x}$, $C$, and $D$ must be pairwise distinct.
Otherwise $x$ and $y$ are not a couple, and by condition 2 there must be some club $C_{xy}$ in which both $x$ and $y$ are members.
Now $C_{xy}$, $C$, and $D$ must be pairwise distinct clubs, and $u\not\in C_{xy}$ by condition 2.
Suppose $w \in C_{xy}\setminus \{x,y\}$.
By condition 2, $w\not\in C$ and also $w\not\in D$, so $w=v$.
This means that the clubs $C_{xy}$ either contain only $x$ and $y$, or contain $x$, $y$, and $v$ and no other members.
Since there must be a club $C_{xy}$ for each $x\in C\setminus \{u\}$ and $y\in D\setminus \{u\}$ that are not partners, there are at least $(n-1)(n-2)$ such clubs.

If $n=2$ then there are no such clubs $C_{xy}$, but denoting the other couple by $x,y$, there are at least the four distinct clubs $C$, $D$, $E_{xv|y}$, and $E_{yv|x}$.
This can be achieved with $k=4$ clubs that each have precisely two of the people as members.
So now suppose $n\ge 3$, when there exist some such clubs $C_{xy}$.
Then there must be at least $(n-1)(n-2)+2$ clubs.
Now let $C_{xy}=\{x,y\}$ for each $x \in C\setminus \{u\}$ and $y \in D\setminus \{u\}$ that are not a couple.
*Now pick a set of pairs* $\{(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),\dots,(x_{n-1},y_{n-1})\} \subseteq (C\setminus \{u\})\times (D\setminus\{u\})$ *such that* $\{u,x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{n-1},y_1,y_2,\dots,y_{n-1}\} = C\cup D$ *and* $x_i,y_i$ *are not a couple for any* $i = 1,2,\dots n-1$, *and add* $v$ *to* $C_{x_i y_i}$ *for each* $i=1,2,\dots,n-1$.
There are precisely $(n-1)(n-2)+2$ such clubs, and these satisfy all three conditions.
Hence this system achieves the smallest possible $k$ and has $(n-1)(n-2)+2$ clubs.

In the case $n=5$ this is $k = 14$ clubs; in this system $u$ is a member of two clubs with $5$ members each, $v$ belongs to *four* clubs with three members each, and the other $8$ people belong to four clubs each, one with $5$ members <strike>and three with three</strike>, *one with three, and two with two*.

*Thanks to @bof for pointing out an error in the witness I was proposing for the upper bound, and to @browngreen for an error in the final summary; the parts in italics indicate the fix.*

Comment: @bof, you are right that we can't add $v$ to all the sets $C_{xy}$.  I have changed the construction.

Comment: In the last sentence, shouldn't the other 8 people belong to *four* clubs each, one with 5 members, one with three, and *two* with two?  According to the way you have it, each of the 8 people will end up being with 9 other people total when they should really only be with 8.

Comment: @browngreen, thanks, now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I would go about this problem in the following way:

Let $A$ be the person who is in exactly 2 clubs (which we can call $Club1$ and $Club2$), and let $B$ be the couple partner of $A$.  Since $A$ must be in exactly one club with every person other than B, the remaining 8 people must each belong to exactly one of $A$'s 2 clubs. Furthermore, since those 8 people consist of 4 couples, they must be divided 4 and 4, such that one member of each couple is in $Club1$ and the other member of each couple is in $Club2$.

Now each of the 4 people in $Club1$ (other than $A$) must still be in a club with each of the 4 non-$A$ people in $Club2$ other than their partner.  But since none of the $Club1$ members can be in any more clubs together, nor can any of the $Club2$ members be in any more clubs together, each of the 4 $Club1$ members will have to form individual clubs to be with each of the 3 non-partner non-$A$ members in $Club2$. This creates 12 additional clubs.

The only thing left is that $B$ needs to be in a club with each of the other 8 people (besides for $A$).  However, this can be done without creating any additional clubs. $B$ can join 4 of the aforementioned 12 clubs in such a way that they will be with each of the 8 people exactly once. For example, if we call the $Club1$ members $X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4$ and the $Club2$ members $Y_1,Y_2,Y_3,Y_4$ with the corresponding numbers being the couples, $B$ can join the clubs $(X_1,Y_2),(X_2,Y_3),(X_3,Y_4),(X_4,Y_1)$.

Therefore, we end up with a total of 14 groups, and 14 is the minimum value of $k$.

For a more general solution with $n$ couples, you can use the same method. $A$ will be in 2 clubs, each with $n-1$ other people. Assuming $n-1$ is at least 2, then each of the $n-1$ people from $Club1$ will form a club with each of the $n-2$ people from $Club2$ that are not their partner and not $A$, creating $(n-1)(n-2)$ additional clubs. $B$ can then join $n-1$ clubs in a way that they are with everyone (besides $A$) exactly once, without creating any new clubs. (This can always be done by joining the clubs $(X_1,Y_2),(X_2,Y_3),...,(X_{n-1},Y_n),(X_n,Y_1).)$

Therefore the general solution for $n\ge2$ couples is: minimum $k=2+(n-1)(n-2)$

When there are exactly 2 couples $A$ will still be in 2 clubs (with $X$ and with $Y$) but since $X$ and $Y$ can't form a club together, $B$ will have to be in two separate clubs, one with $X$ and one with $Y$, giving a total of 4 clubs.